# jquery $(this).prev(".class") not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this simple setup

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">I'm spoiled</div>
</div>
<div class="aunt"></div>
<div class="uncle"></div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">I'm spoiled</div>
</div>
<div class="aunt"></div>
<div class="uncle"></div>
```

When I detect a click on class "uncle", I want to get the sibling of the closest previous ".parent". I should be able to do

```
$( this ).prev( ".parent" ).children( ".child" ).text();
```

...but this returns a blank.

If I do

```
$( this ).prev().prev().children( ".child" ).text();
```

...this returns the expected result: "I'm spoiled"

Is there some limitations to the use of prev( [selector] ) I'm missing?

[UPDATE]

.prevAll() returns all previuos classes, so the result of

```
$( this ).prevAll( ".parent" ).children( ".child" ).text();
```

Is "I'm spoiledI'm spoiled" if I click on the second ".uncle", which is not the result I want.

I just need the immediate closest previous one.

Answer (score 10):

From the jquery documentation:

> .prev() Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Also:

> To select all preceding sibling elements, rather than just the preceding adjacent sibling, use the .prevAll() method.

So, there you go, use the .prevAll() method instead.
http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Updated my question to reflect why I cant use prevAll()

Comment: use $( this ).prevAll( ".parent:first" ).children( ".child" ).text();

Comment: @George: that's what I would suggest as well.

Comment: @George, thanks, but this would provide the same answer if I click on the second uncle...

Comment: have you tried $( this ).prevAll( ".parent:last" ).children( ".child" ).text(); ? I'm not sure what order jquery parses the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

That's because that's not what prev was intended to do.  You are trying to use prev in the way .prevAll() is supposed to work.

EDIT:

Considering your latest requirements, I would think something like this would work:

```
$(this).prevUntil(".parent").first().prev().children( ".child" ).text()
```

Comment: Updated my question to show why .prevAll() doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this solution solves it, but not as smooth as I would like :)

Answer (score 1):

prev() returns only the first preceeding element.

**Try:**

```
$( this ).prevAll( ".parent:first" ).children( ".child" ).text();
```

Answer (score -1):

this may be better way:

```
var this = $(this);
var.parent('.parent').prev().children('.children').text();
```